# Rename AntiForgeryToken Hidden Input Name from __RequestVerificationToken

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, csrf

(Doing this to obfuscate ASP.NET MVC Framework in web app.)

Have renamed the cookie name with static AntiForgeryConfig class via Helpers in Application_Start.

**Global.asax**:

```
AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName = "Test";
```

But still obvious AntiForgeryToken is being used due to input name:

**Front End**:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="blahblahblah" />
```

Arguably the value smells of MVC with encoding but not really sure what to about this. (Different issue really but comments/other approaches welcomed and appreciated regardless.)

Comment: Using the class and the property for me works using MVC version 4. Verified using Firebug. You should specify the version of MVC you're using.

Comment: Could you post this as an answer with code please? Version is ASP.NET MVC 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After checking the source code on CodePlex, it appears that this value is hard-coded as a constant. So there's no easy way of changing this value. You can see this here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiForgeryConfig.cs

I'm surprised it's not configurable. Anyways, it appears that what you want to do is not possible.

However, I advice you create a feature request on Codeplex and hope they will implement it.

Note: If you want to go really hardcore, you could always download the code and make the modification, but this will probably give you more problems than it solves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you give more detail/example/a link on the hardcore approach? Never gone this far (like you said can cause issues) but want to atleast try it out. Played with namespaces, classes, dlls etc. to override but not made any tangible progress.

Comment: What you could do is download the source code from Codeplex, modify it and rebuild it. This is not trivial, but since it's open source, it's now an option.

Comment: It sounds like your only just getting started with .net in general; I'd therefore advise against tampering with the built in security for trivial changes. Embrace that msft are trying to give you security by default, go forwards and make great things :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925446/how-to-get-antiforgerytoken-value-without-hidden-input) should get you started.

Changing the input name is non-trivial. Both the `Html.AntiForgeryToken` helper and the `ValidationAntiforgeryToken` attribute rely on the input name being "__RequestVerificationToken". If you want it to be something else, you will need to drop down into using the AntiForgery API and create your own versions of both helper and attribute to validate against your chosen name.