# Why can't I get the vaue of __RequestVerificationToken from AngularJS or even pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, cookies

I am writing a front-end application with Bootstrap and AngularJS for a C# MVC back-end code.

Using Chrome's developer console (and any other browser, including IE), I can see a cookie called `__RequestVerificationToken`, as the image below shows:

[image]

I understand this is a technique used to prevent [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks. Anyway, since this cookie is there, I was trying to get it's value using AngluarJS module `$cookies`, but it always returns `undefined`, and printing `document.cookie` doesn't show it. Below is the code used:

```
...
this.initApp = function () {
    console.log('Value of __RequestVerificationToken: "' + $cookies.__RequestVerificationToken + '"'); // Angular way
    console.log('Cookie: "' + document.cookie + '"'); // Pure JavaScript
};
...
```

So my question is, why can't I get its value if the cookie is there and is being sent to the client in every single response, and how do I get its value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute that writes a unique value to an HTTP-only cookie before your action. You also should add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your form and the same value is written to the form as a hidden field.

```
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid Razor syntax in my View, is there any other way? Of course if that's the only solution I'm going for it.

Comment: You can take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925446/how-to-get-antiforgerytoken-value-without-hidden-input)

Answer (score 1):

Normally __RequestVerificationToken is HttpOnly, so it is not accessible by client script. 
What is strange on your picture there is no flag in column HTTP.
It should be similar to this picture - see HTTP check highlighted:

[image]