# Providing Antiforgery Token to Native Mobile Apps

Tags: ios, .net, asp.net-mvc, security, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET WebApi solution in place with all clients using **Forms Auth**.   My MVC consumers are using the following:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

And then on all of my API endpoints I validate that the token is set in the header via a `WebApiValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`.

As I develop my iOS application, I've decided to maintain cookies as an auth mechanism.  How do I go about generating this token in the iOS client applications?

**UPDATE**

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925446/how-to-get-antiforgerytoken-value-without-hidden-input), I've done the following:

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/getAntiForgeryToken/{oldCookieToken?}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAntiForgeryToken(string oldCookieToken = null) {
        var model = new AntiforgeryDto();
        string newCookieToken;
        string newFormToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(oldCookieToken, out newCookieToken, out newFormToken);
        model.CookieToken = newCookieToken;
        model.FormToken = newFormToken;
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, model);
        response.Headers.AddCookies(new List<CookieHeaderValue>(){ new CookieHeaderValue("__RequestVerificationToken", model.CookieToken)});
        return response;
    }
```

Although I'm not sure if this approach is secure.  Should I somehow be validating that the client requesting the token is the mobile app?